# Confused about when to use the Indicative tense and the Subjunctive tense

Tags: subjuntivo, presente-indicativo

I was completing a worksheet that my Spanish teacher had assigned me, but I am not 100% sure that I am correct. I know that you use the indicative mood during the act of certainty, and you use the subjunctive tense when you are doubtful or unsure on the validity of the statement. Can someone tell me if I know when to properly use each tense and check if what I have are correct?

---

Mi mamá duda que yo *1. haga* toda la tarea todos los días.

Yo sé que tú puedes *2. sacar* buenas notas en esta clase.

Mi hermanito se alegra de que sus amigos *3. son* tan comprensivos. Siempre le ayuda cuando está triste.

Es evidente que nosotros *4. preferimos* ir a la escuela. No les gusta tomar clases desde casa porque es aburrido.

Es dudoso que Shakira *5. venga* a California para hacer un concierto este mes.

Vivimos en una ciudad que *6. tiene* muchas casas de dos pisos.

No hay nadie que *7. sepa* por qué desapareció la civilización maya.

Buscamos un libro que *8. explica* bien la historia de la Segunda Guerra Mundial.

Quiero encontrar unos vestidos bonitos que *9. están* baratos.

Mi hermana y yo tenemos unos amigos que *10. conocemos* bien la Ciudad de México. Pensamos visitarlos este verano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Correcto. Es subjuntivo porque expresa duda.
2. Correcto. Es un infinitivo, porque poder va siempre con verbos en infinitivo.
3. Incorrecto. Tiene que ser subjuntivo porque se expresa una valoración: *se alegra*.
4. Correcto. Es indicativo porque es una afirmación en positivo.
5. Correcto. Es subjuntivo porque expresa duda.
6. Correcto. Es indicativo porque es una afirmación en positivo.
7. Correcto. Es subjuntivo porque es una afirmación en negativo.
8. Creo que incorrecto. Depende de qué se quiera decir.

*Buscamos un libro que explique bien la historia* significa que queremos encontrar algún libro que explique bien la historia, cualquier libro que explique bien la historia nos vale. No estamos afirmando que un libro determinado explica bien la historia, con lo que no puede ser indicativo.

*Buscamos un libro que explica bien la historia* significa que queremos encontrar un libro, sabemos exactamente qué libro es y afirmamos que ese libro que estamos pensando explica bien la historia.

9. Creo que incorrecto. Igual que en el caso anterior.
10. Incorrecto. Es verdad que es indicativo, porque es una afirmación en positivo, pero la oración subordinada se refiere a *unos amigos*, con lo que la forma correcta es *conocen*.